# How can I find why my merge sorting algorithm crash when sorting an array of 1 million element?

Tags: c, arrays, crash, time-complexity, mergesort

I'm a French student and trying to calculate the execution time of the Merge Sort algorithm for different size of array. 
I also want to write the different execution time in a .csv file. But when my program tries to sort an array with 1 million elements the process returns `-1073741571 (0xC00000FD)` in Code::Blocks. So if you could point me to a way to find a solution I would be very grateful!

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

void genTab(int *tab, int n) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        tab[i] = rand() % 100;  
    }
}

void fusion(int *tab, int deb, int mid, int fin) {
    int i = deb;
    int j = mid + 1;
    int k = deb;
    int temp[fin + 1];
    while ((i <= mid) && (j <= fin)) {
        if (tab[i] <= tab[j]) {
            temp[k] = tab[i];
            i++;
        } else {
            temp[k] = tab[j];
            j++;
        }
        k++;
    }
    while (i <= mid) {
        temp[k] = tab[i];
        i++;
        k++;
    }
    while (j <= fin) {
       temp[k] = tab[j];
       k++;
       j++;
    }

    for (i = deb; i <= fin; i++) {
        tab[i] = temp[i];
    }
}

void triFusion(int *tab, int i, int j) {
    if (i < j) {
        triFusion(tab, i, (int)((i + j) / 2));
        triFusion(tab, (int)((i + j) / 2 + 1), j);
        fusion(tab, i, (int)((i + j) / 2), j);
    }
}

void reset(int *tab1, int *tab2, int n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {       
        tab2[i] = tab1[i];
    }
}

int main() {
    srand(time(NULL));
    clock_t start, end;  

    int nbrTest[15] = {
        1000, 5000, 10000, 50000, 80000, 100000, 120000, 140000,
        150000, 180000, 200000, 250000, 300000, 450000, 1000000
    }; 
    FILE *fp;

    char *tpsExecution = "exeTime.csv";

    fp = fopen(tpsExecution, "w");

    fprintf(fp, "Array Size; Merge Time"); 

    for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {     
        int n = nbrTest[i];
        printf("Calculating time for an array of %d \n", n);
        int *tab = malloc(sizeof(int) * n);
        genTab(tab, n);      

        int *copie = malloc(sizeof(int) * n);
        reset(tab, copie, n);

        start = clock();
        triFusion(tab, 0, n - 1);
        end = clock();
        float tpsFusion = (float)(end - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

        reset(tab, copie, n);

        printf("writing in the file\n");
        fprintf(fp, "\n%d;%f", n, tpsFusion);    
        free(tab);
        free(copie);
    }
    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Note: posted after the answer from @Eric Postpischil).

The function

```
void fusion(int * tab, int deb, int mid, int fin)
```

Has the line

```
int temp[fin+1];
```

and the value of `fin` comes through another function from the number of elements `n` to be sorted

```
triFusion(tab, 0, n-1);
```

and as an automatic variable, breaks the stack when `n` is large.

I suggest replacing the line with

```
int *temp = malloc((fin+1) * sizeof *temp);
if(temp == NULL) {
    puts("malloc");
    exit(1);
}

// ...

free(temp);
```

Comment: Thank you for your help ! I got it that there is something messy with the `n` being too large but I what is doing the 'puts()' function ?

Comment: The `puts` is a cheap way of informing `malloc` failure, but should be something better.

Comment: Allocation `malloc((fin+1) * sizeof *temp);` in each recursive call is wasteful. For a set of 1 million elements, the memory required for the sort will be up to 80 MB instead of just 4 MB, or even 2 MB with a slightly more elaborate approach.

Answer (score 2):

`int temp[fin+1];` may exceed the space limit for the stack. You should allocate it with `malloc` instead, and free it with `free`.

If you want to exclude `malloc` and `free` from the timed code, the allocation could be performed outside the timed code and passed in as work space.

Comment: yes it work now ! thank you very much !! I was supposing that there was a problem with stack limit but I forgot this array, I should have seen it ^^' 
Thank you again !

Comment: Eric you were first so +1. I was busy testing the modified code.

Answer (score 1):

fusion() is always allocating the full size of the array for temp, even when only a small fraction of temp is being used. You could change this to:

```
int k = 0;
...
int temp[fin+1-deb];
...
tab[i]=temp[i-deb];
```

still this will exceed stack space if n is large. So as suggested in the other answers:

```
int k = 0;
...
int *temp = malloc((fin+1-deb)*sizeof(int));
...
tab[i]=temp[i-deb];
...
free(temp)
```

or better still, do a one time allocation of a second array in main or in a "helper" function, the include a pointer to the second array in the merge sort functions.